# Pub/Sub Authentication concept for decentral publisher

Tags: rest, authentication, google-cloud-pubsub

**Context:** We are hosting an online shop that needs to track customer behaviour. To achieve this tracking we have integrated several tracking events based on the customer journey in our shop. Based on the GDPR requirements in Europe we are forced to send the tracking events to infrastructure that is controlled by us as a company. Sending data via the Google Analytics Tag Manager directly to Google Servers is forbidden by the GDPR law. Sidenote: To simplify this question, I intentionally leave out all stuff regards user consent management.

**Problem statement:** We have the need that each client sends every tracking event directly from the browser to a Pub/Sub endpoint. Now, my question is how a best practise for a proper security would look like.

**Current proposal:** The Pub/Sub endpoint doesn't require an authentication --> AllUsers have been granted Pub/Sub Publisher permission. In addition I've created an API-KEY that is restricted to

- the Pub/Sub API only
- to specific HTTP referrers (basically the domain our webshop operates)

Are there other strategies that could be applied? Is the current proposal a valid (aka secure) way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Giving pub/sub publisher access to allUsers are not recommended. Create service account and give publisher access to that and send messages using that service account.